# Why is bmp created as not transparent?

Tags: c++, windows, clipboard

I have following code which creates transparent bmp image and saves it to clipboard. After this I tried to copy this to Photoshop or office, Gimp. But image is not transparent:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Wingdi.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

pair<int, HGLOBAL> dibv5_img(void)
{
    const DWORD width = 100;
    const DWORD height = 100;
    BITMAPV5HEADER header = {0};
    header.bV5Size = sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER);
    header.bV5Width = width;
    header.bV5Height = -height;
    header.bV5Planes = 1;
    header.bV5BitCount = 32;
    header.bV5Compression = BI_BITFIELDS;
    header.bV5SizeImage = header.bV5Width * header.bV5Height *     header.bV5BitCount / 8;
    header.bV5CSType = LCS_WINDOWS_COLOR_SPACE;
    header.bV5Intent = LCS_GM_IMAGES;

    header.bV5BlueMask = 0x000000FF;
    header.bV5GreenMask = 0x0000FF00;
    header.bV5RedMask = 0x00FF0000;
    header.bV5AlphaMask = 0xFF000000;

    DWORD masks[3];
    masks[0] = header.bV5BlueMask;
    masks[1] = header.bV5GreenMask;
    masks[2] = header.bV5AlphaMask;

    DWORD pixels[width * height];
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < height; ++i)
        for (DWORD j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            pixels[i * width + j] = 0;
    for (DWORD i = height / 4; i < 3 * height / 4; ++i)
        for (DWORD j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            pixels[i * width + j] = (masks[0] | header.bV5AlphaMask) &     0xFFFFFFFF;

    HGLOBAL hmem = GlobalAlloc(GHND | GMEM_DDESHARE, header.bV5Size +     sizeof(DWORD) * (3 + width * height));
    PVOID local_pointer = GlobalLock(hmem);

    memcpy(local_pointer, &header, sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER));
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(local_pointer) +     sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER), masks, sizeof(DWORD) * 3);
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(local_pointer) +     sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER) + sizeof(DWORD) * 3, pixels, 
        sizeof(DWORD) * width * height);
    GlobalUnlock(hmem);
    return pair<int, HGLOBAL>(CF_DIBV5, hmem);
}

int main(void)
{
    cout << sizeof(DWORD) << endl;
    if (!OpenClipboard(0))
        return 1;
    if (!EmptyClipboard())
        return 1;
    const auto data = dibv5_img();
    SetClipboardData(data.first, data.second);
    if (!CloseClipboard())
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Output in all apps is following:

[image]

Comment: Virtually no application supports transparent bitmaps.

Comment: @CodyGray, it seems weird for me. I thought that DIBV5 format, which explicitly tells about presence/absence alpha channel can solve such problem for all applications

Comment: Yes, the bitmap format does support storing alpha-channel information. That isn't what I said. I said that virtually no application supports it. If you want to write an application that stores transparent bitmaps and properly reads transparent bitmaps, then you are free to do so, but don't expect them to be seen as transparent by other people's apps.

Comment: I think this expression `(masks[0] | header.bV5AlphaMask) &     0xFFFFFFFF;` sets alpha to fully opaque.

Comment: @VTT, yes, you are right. I fill blue rectangle with alpha channel which equals FF, other black rectangles should be transparent

Comment: I warned you about this in your previous question.  This code provides the bitmap in 3 distinct formats, BMP, DIB and "Format17" (aka CF_DIBV5).  Everybody will be happy with BMP, some might pick DIB, nobody picks the one you want.  I suppose you'll have to ensure you don't give them a choice.